# Show that $(A-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}B$ is semi local for number ring extension $A\subset B$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization

When $A\subset B$ is an extension of number rings, I want to show that $B_{\mathfrak{p}}=(A-\mathfrak{p})^{-1}B$ is semi local for every prime $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$.

So written differently, $B_{\mathfrak{p}}=\left\{\frac{a}{b}\mid a\in B,\;b\in A-\mathfrak{p}\right\}$.

Can anyone give some type of hint? I'm really lost.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\subset B$ be two integral domains and $P$ a maximal ideal $A$.

For $q$ a prime ideal of $(A-P)^{-1} B$ then $p= q \cap A$ is a prime ideal of $A$. If $p \not\subset P$ there exists $a\in p, a\not \in P$, thus $a^{-1} \in (A-p)^{-1} B$ so that $a\in q \implies a a^{-1}=1 \in q$, a contradiction.

Thus the only prime ideals of $(A-P)^{-1} B$ are those above prime ideals $\subset P$.

If $Frac(A),Frac(B)$ are finite extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ then any non-zero prime ideal is maximal and any quotient of $(A-P)^{-1}B/(c)$ is a finite ring thus there are only finitely many ideals above $P$ and there are finitely many prime ideals in $(A-P)^{-1}B/(c)$.

Comment: What do you mean by "a quotient of $(A-P)^{-1}B/(c)$" and is $c$ some element in $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$?